# Unity - limit/clamp rotateAround()

Tags: unity-game-engine

i have a Unity setup and problem which can be described as follows:

- There is a Pivot Object in the center of a circle and the object i am trying to move is along the perimeter of the circle. (using rotateAround())
- I need to clamp/limit this rotation around the pivot object to about 45 degrees both ways (or 90 degrees total)

I have been trying to do this for more than a month with no success, please help :<

**EDIT:**

This is the line of code i am using currently and it works. The object rotates in a circle correctly, but the result i want is to have a limit/clamp on this rotation.

```
GameObject.Find("rotate_me_around_pivot_object").transform.RotateAround(GameObject.Find("PivotObject").transform.position, Vector3.forward, 5 * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: If possible, add code which you have tried to the question. It might be easier to answer by making edits to it. Also clarify the problem. Is it that the object is not rotating at all or the rotation is not limited like you wanted or it is behaving strangely?

Comment: Next time you get stuck at something like this for more than a day, ask right away. Saves you an entire month of troubles. The answer is probably simple trigonometry, ie distance vectore between the pivot and the object, calculate angle relative to vector3.right, check if angle is < or > than whatever range you need.

Comment: Did you find a solution?